# Java Swing: How to remove an anonymous ActionListener from a component

Tags: java, swing

I created an array of `JButtons` with anonymous `ActionListeners` and under certain conditions I want to remove all the `ActionListeners`, but the `.removeActionListeners` method requires an `ActionListener` as an argument. How would I go about removing the action listeners?

```
for (int i=0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i] = new JButton();
    button[i].addActionListener(listener.new ButtonListener());
}
```

Comment: (Just a note that this probably isn't an effective way to design whatever you are trying to do. Better leave the listeners there firing, and have some check/polymorphism after that to disable the action (probably switch state rather than disable).)

Answer (score 25):

You can get them with: [getActionListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getActionListeners()) method:

```
for( JButton currentButton: button ) {
    for( ActionListener al : currentButton.getActionListeners() ) {
        currentButton.removeActionListener( al );
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it will thrown a `ConcurrentModificationException` though.

Comment: Probably not...I'm willing to bet it stores the listeners internally as an ArrayList and then copies them into an array of ActionListeners to return them.  Curious to see if it would though...

Comment: Nobody would return an internal array, would they? (Which doesn't resize anyway.)

Comment: for( ActionListener al : button.getActionListeners() )      That won't compile but it was a nice idea

Comment: for (JButton b: button)    
     for( ActionListener al : b.getActionListeners() ) 
      b.removeActionListener(al); That works

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question, and as others have suggested, iterating through all the actions listeners from the client class may solve your immediate problem.

1. H/w in this case, what you are really trying to do is extend the functionality of a JButton, and that is one way to tackle this problem - extend JButton and add a method called `removeAllActionListeners()` (which does not take any parameters).

   - Inside this method you can iterate
     through all action listeners and
     remove them. I think it is better
     design if you do this here than in
     the client class.
2. If you don't want to do that, then I think Tom Hawtin's suggestion to use state within your ButtonListener is a good idea.
3. Failing which, you always have the option of falling back on a very "hacky" way, which is to store a collection of the action listeners in your client class.

   - `Map<JButton, ButtonListener>` (if there's always only going to be one listener per button), or
   - `Map<JButton, List<ButtonListener>>` (if there can be multiple listeners per button) is what I might use.

I think methods **1** and **2** are preferable, and method **3** indicates poor design (but is much easier to hack together).

Note that, if you do indeed use method **1**, or something similar, check that the methods or attributes you are accessing are thread safe (as mentioned by OscarRyz), and if not, use `synchronized` to ensure thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Nobody has a reference to those objects.  In order to be able to remove them you'll need to store it as a data member/variable in your code and then pass that variable to the `removeActionListener()` method.  However, what you could do is use the `getActionListeners()` method to get an array of all of the `ActionListener` objects associated with the `Button`.  You'll then need to figure out which one to remove, but if there's only one, that should be easy ;-)