# Slow running, High memory usage

Tags: java, performance, memory

I'm writing a small text-based game for my class. The navigation is simple, in which the player clicks buttons to enter a different part. All of these parts are separated into their own blocks of code. I've set up only two parts so far, each of them being able to reach one another through buttons. Basically:

```
private void level1() {
//Stuff here, player clicks a button which runs "level2();"
}

private void level2() {
//Stuff here, player clicks a button which runs "level1();"
}
```

So that works just fine, but after some clicking back and forth between 1 & 2, the program starts to run very slow. Task Manager reports about 700MB of memory usage.

I'm sure there's something real obvious that I'm missing. I'm looking for a way for the user to be able to click many buttons, many times, and not make the program use so much resources. Help would be very much appreciated.

Edit: Some more code. Choice1-3 are the names for the buttons. Variables are already declared at the top of the program, and set up in the initialize part. They're to be modified with each block of code, such as Scene1 and 2.

```
private void setScene1() // TITLE SCREEN
{
    TITLE.setText("Title Label");
    main.setText("Main text body for the game.");
    choice1.setText("Play");
    choice1.setBounds(10, 600, 996, 91); // This makes choice1 as large as
                                            // all three buttons combined.
    choice2.setEnabled(false);// There's only one option anyway.
    choice3.setEnabled(false);
    choice2.setVisible(false);
    choice3.setVisible(false);

    choice1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            setScene2();
        }
    });

}

private void setScene2() // CHARACTER GENERATION SCENE
{
    TITLE.setText("Character Generation");
    main.setEnabled(false); // Disable & Hide the main text window, as
                            // Chargen requires a nicer looking interface.
    main.setVisible(false);
    choice2.setEnabled(true);
    choice2.setVisible(true);
    choice1.setBounds(10, 600, 996, 34); //Resizing the bottom portion to fit two buttons
    choice2.setBounds(10, 645, 996, 34);
    choice1.setText("Continue");
    choice1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Nothing here for now
        }
    });
    choice2.setText("Back to the Title Screen");
    choice2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            main.setEnabled(true);
            main.setVisible(true);
            setScene1();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Where is the code? Without it SO cannot really help

Comment: Can you show us the `onClick` events for level1() and level2()? My first guess is that you're creating new objects instead of re-using ones that already exist. If you click enough you'd end up having numerous `level1` and `level2` objects but only one active/visible at a time.

Comment: Right, sorry. I just added some more now. I am indeed re-using objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the fact that you're adding an ActionListener every time you switch scenes.  The previous ActionListener is never going away, but you're stacking more on top of it that do the same thing.  Each one performs the same action, so when you press to switch scene, all the ActionListners that it now has will also go to switch scene.  Your CPU will go up because there's now 2^n ActionListeners waiting for input and there's that many sitting in memory.

Comment: So from this and the previous answer, I've just got a ton of different processes running in the background that aren't doing anything? Is there anything I can do to terminate these methods?

Comment: You can use the component's getActionListeners() method, then loop through and do removeActionListener() on each of those.  There's an example describing how to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048006/java-swing-how-to-remove-an-anonymous-actionlistener-from-a-component

Comment: The much more recommended way to fix your problem is to only add the ActionListeners when you instantiate the objects they're being attached to, not every time you set your scene.  Your scenes should really just be two different JLayers with their own components that you flip in and out instead of rewriting the properties of all those components every time.

Comment: Of course, thanks for the advice. After putting in the loop with getActionListeners and removeActionsListeners, I ran the program, and could flip through both menus without trouble. 

It all works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the two methods continue to call each other you'll eventually eat through your memory: this is recursion. If you never return up the call tree it just gets arbitrarily deep until boom.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the ActionListeners in the Constructor or somewhere else. This way you add a new ActionListener each time (even if it's the same) you press the button.