# How to remove action listener? Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

This is very crude code, I'm trying to remove an action listener here because whenever I press the new button twice, it adds in another action listener and breaks my code. I'd like for it just to add a new action listener whenever I click new and remove it when it is done with it.

Currently, this code works completely except for the remove action listener bit, which gives the error  `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` when I hover over "btnGuess" in the line  `for( JButton currentButton: btnGuess ) {`

```
btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
        lblQuestion.setText("What is the symbol of " + elements[random]);
        btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int correct = 0, incorrect = 0, limit = 0;
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String correctanswers = symbols[random];
                String userAnswer = getUserAnswer();
                String answer = "";
                System.out.println("user " + userAnswer);
                System.out.println("correct " + correctanswers);
                if (userAnswer.equals(correctanswers)) {
                    answer = "Correct";
                    correct = correct + 1;
                } else {
                    answer = "Incorrect";
                    incorrect = incorrect + 1;
                }
                lblcountcorrect.setText(String.valueOf(correct));
                lblcountincorrect.setText(String.valueOf(incorrect));
                lblFeedback.setText("You were " + answer);
            }
        });
    }
});

for (JButton currentButton: btnGuess) {
    for (ActionListener al: currentButton.getActionListeners()) {
        currentButton.removeActionListener(al);
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is my updated code to the full:
As you can see, the console shows 2 more new outputs but keeps the 2 old ones everytime you click new. This also messes with my counter and correct/incorrect output.

```
package SwingPrograms;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Iterable;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;

public class periodicTable extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textBoxGuess;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    periodicTable frame = new periodicTable();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public periodicTable() {
        
        String[] elements = goReadTextFile("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\1 java\\elements.txt");
        String[] symbols = goReadTextFile("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\1 java\\symbols.txt");
        int correct = 0, incorrect = 0;
        //when button "next" is clicked come back here
        int min = 1, max = elements.length;
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1067, 742);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        
        JLabel lblQuestion = new JLabel("What is the symbol of ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblQuestion.setBounds(10, 11, 1031, 110);
        contentPane.add(lblQuestion);
        
        
        JButton btnNew = new JButton("NEW");
        /*btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    
                lblQuestion.setText("What is the symbol of " + elements[random]);
                String correctanswers = symbols[random];
            }

        });*/
        btnNew.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        btnNew.setBounds(315, 114, 162, 49);
        contentPane.add(btnNew);
        
        textBoxGuess = new JTextField();
        textBoxGuess.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 99));
        textBoxGuess.setBounds(296, 174, 205, 100);
        contentPane.add(textBoxGuess);
        textBoxGuess.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnGuess = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        btnGuess.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        btnGuess.setBounds(544, 203, 241, 49);
        contentPane.add(btnGuess);
          
        JLabel lblFeedback = new JLabel("You were ");
        lblFeedback.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblFeedback.setBounds(315, 398, 470, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblFeedback);
        
        
        JLabel lblcorrect = new JLabel("Correct Answers");
        lblcorrect.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lblcorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblcorrect.setBounds(36, 396, 172, 80);
        contentPane.add(lblcorrect);
        
        JLabel lblincorrect = new JLabel("Incorrect Answers");
        lblincorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblincorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblincorrect.setBounds(818, 402, 187, 69);
        contentPane.add(lblincorrect);
        
        JLabel lblcountcorrect = new JLabel(String.valueOf(correct));
        lblcountcorrect.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lblcountcorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));
        lblcountcorrect.setBounds(36, 472, 172, 110);
        contentPane.add(lblcountcorrect);
        
        JLabel lblcountincorrect = new JLabel(String.valueOf(incorrect));
        lblcountincorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblcountincorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));
        lblcountincorrect.setBounds(818, 487, 187, 95);
        contentPane.add(lblcountincorrect);
        

        btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

                
                lblQuestion.setText("What is the symbol of " + elements[random]);

        btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
            int correct=0,incorrect=0, limit=0;
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)            {
                String correctanswers = symbols[random];
                
                String userAnswer = getUserAnswer();
                String answer = "";
                System.out.println("user " + userAnswer);
                System.out.println("correct " + correctanswers);
                
                if (userAnswer.equals(correctanswers)) {
                    answer = "Correct";
                    correct=correct+1;
                }
                else {
                    answer = "Incorrect";
                    incorrect=incorrect+1;
                }
                
            lblcountcorrect.setText(String.valueOf(correct));
            lblcountincorrect.setText(String.valueOf(incorrect));
            lblFeedback.setText("You were " + answer);
        

            }
            
        }); 

            }

        });
        for( JButton currentButton: btnGuess ) {
            for( ActionListener al : currentButton.getActionListeners() ) {
                currentButton.removeActionListener( al );
            }
        }
    
        //need to figure out counter, and next button
    }
    
    
    public static String[] goReadTextFile(String Location) {
         String fileName = Location ;
           String line;
           int Count = 0;
           int length = 0;
           try
           {      
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName  ) ); //this code finds the length of the file, so can add new elements no hardcode length
             
             line = in.readLine();
             while ( line != null )  // while not end of file
             {
               length=length+1;
               line = in.readLine();
             }
             in.close();
           }
           catch(IOException iox) { 
               System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName );
           }
           
           String[] temp = new String[length];
           try
           {      
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName  ) ); //this puts the txt file into a temp array
             
             line = in.readLine();
             while ( line != null )  // while not end of file
             {
            
               temp[Count]=line;
               Count=Count+1;
               line = in.readLine();
             }
             in.close();
           }
           catch ( IOException iox )
           {
             System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName );
           }
        return temp;
    }
    
    
    public String getUserAnswer() {
        return textBoxGuess.getText();
    }
}
```

Once more another edit:
I have ammended my code thanks to the suggestions of the comments, it now works how I have intended except my correct/incorect counter has broken, any ideas how to fix it?

```
package SwingPrograms;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Iterable;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;

public class periodicTable extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textBoxGuess;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    periodicTable frame = new periodicTable();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public periodicTable() {
        
        String[] elements = goReadTextFile("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\1 java\\elements.txt");
        String[] symbols = goReadTextFile("C:\\Users\\Allan\\Documents\\1 java\\symbols.txt");
        int correct = 0, incorrect = 0;
        //when button "next" is clicked come back here
        int min = 1, max = elements.length;
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1067, 742);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        
        JLabel lblQuestion = new JLabel("What is the symbol of ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblQuestion.setBounds(10, 11, 1031, 110);
        contentPane.add(lblQuestion);
        
        
        JButton btnNew = new JButton("NEW");
        /*btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    
                lblQuestion.setText("What is the symbol of " + elements[random]);
                String correctanswers = symbols[random];
            }

        });*/
        btnNew.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        btnNew.setBounds(315, 114, 162, 49);
        contentPane.add(btnNew);
        
        textBoxGuess = new JTextField();
        textBoxGuess.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 99));
        textBoxGuess.setBounds(296, 174, 205, 100);
        contentPane.add(textBoxGuess);
        textBoxGuess.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnGuess = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        btnGuess.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 50));
        btnGuess.setBounds(544, 203, 241, 49);
        contentPane.add(btnGuess);
          
        JLabel lblFeedback = new JLabel("You were ");
        lblFeedback.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblFeedback.setBounds(315, 398, 470, 60);
        contentPane.add(lblFeedback);
        
        
        JLabel lblcorrect = new JLabel("Correct Answers");
        lblcorrect.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lblcorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblcorrect.setBounds(36, 396, 172, 80);
        contentPane.add(lblcorrect);
        
        JLabel lblincorrect = new JLabel("Incorrect Answers");
        lblincorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblincorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblincorrect.setBounds(818, 402, 187, 69);
        contentPane.add(lblincorrect);
        
        JLabel lblcountcorrect = new JLabel(String.valueOf(correct));
        lblcountcorrect.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        lblcountcorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));
        lblcountcorrect.setBounds(36, 472, 172, 110);
        contentPane.add(lblcountcorrect);
        
        JLabel lblcountincorrect = new JLabel(String.valueOf(incorrect));
        lblcountincorrect.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblcountincorrect.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));
        lblcountincorrect.setBounds(818, 487, 187, 95);
        contentPane.add(lblcountincorrect);
        

        btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int random = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);

                
                lblQuestion.setText("What is the symbol of " + elements[random]);
                
        btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
            int correct,incorrect;
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)            {
                String correctanswers = symbols[random];
                
                String userAnswer = getUserAnswer();
                String answer = "";
                System.out.println("user " + userAnswer);
                System.out.println("correct " + correctanswers);
                
                if (userAnswer.equals(correctanswers)) {
                    answer = "Correct";
                    correct++;
                }
                else {
                    answer = "Incorrect";
                    incorrect++;
                }
                
            lblcountcorrect.setText(String.valueOf(correct));
            lblcountincorrect.setText(String.valueOf(incorrect));
            lblFeedback.setText("You were " + answer);
        
            for( ActionListener al : btnGuess.getActionListeners() ) {
                btnGuess.removeActionListener( al );
            }
            }
    
        }); 

            }

        });
        
    }
    
    
    public static String[] goReadTextFile(String Location) {
         String fileName = Location ;
           String line;
           int Count = 0;
           int length = 0;
           try
           {      
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName  ) ); //this code finds the length of the file, so can add new elements no hardcode length
             
             line = in.readLine();
             while ( line != null )  // while not end of file
             {
               length=length+1;
               line = in.readLine();
             }
             in.close();
           }
           catch(IOException iox) { 
               System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName );
           }
           
           String[] temp = new String[length];
           try
           {      
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName  ) ); //this puts the txt file into a temp array
             
             line = in.readLine();
             while ( line != null )  // while not end of file
             {
            
               temp[Count]=line;
               Count=Count+1;
               line = in.readLine();
             }
             in.close();
           }
           catch ( IOException iox )
           {
             System.out.println("Problem reading " + fileName );
           }
        return temp;
    }
    
    
    public String getUserAnswer() {
        return textBoxGuess.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: `btnGuess` looks like to be just a `JButton`, so it doesn't make sense to "iterate" over it in a loop. Remove that outer loop `for( JButton currentButton: btnGuess ) {` and use just `for( ActionListener al : btnGuess.getActionListeners() ) {`

Comment: IMHO dynamically adding / removing ActionListeners is a design smell. Your code should add ActionListeners when you create the UI (before showing it to the user) and you normally should have no reason to remove those ActionListeners.

Comment: @QBrute According to the first answer of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048006/java-swing-how-to-remove-an-anonymous-actionlistener-from-a-component question, iterating over JButtons appears possible, i dont understand why though.

Comment: Hold up, in this example the array is named button for whatever reason. Yet this answer could be the reason OP made this mistake in his code.

Comment: @RAVNMateus in the linked answer, the loop is iterating over a `JButton[]`, not a `JButton`. Likely a copy-paste error from the linked answer to this question.

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what i meant with the second comment